# unable to upload project in aws device farm

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

When i tried to upload my maven project getting an exception like

> There was a problem processing your file. We could not find a *-tests.jar file in the *root* of your test package. Please unzip your test package, verify that at least one *-tests.jar file is in the root of your package, and try again.

But i have created my Clubcard-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar and which is stored under target folder.

Also tried locating the jar file under root folder but still getting same issue

Comment: Can you share the run URL of your run?

Comment: @NikofTime the run command is `mvn test -DtestNG.file=/path/to/testng.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You uploaded the wrong zip file. Did you just try to upload your MAVEN project?

No, it should be a zip file named `zip-with-dependencies.zip` under `target` folder of your maven project. For example, `\Desktop\Appium-myApp\target\zip-with-dependencies.zip`.

If you didn't find your `zip-with-dependencies.zip`, you have to package with maven command

1. Read [the document of Amazon Device Farm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html), you have to setup your pom.xml first
2. `cd` to your maven directory in Terminal or command prompt
3. `mvn clean package –-DskipTests=true` to package into a `*-tests.jar` and `zip-with-dependencies.zip`

Finally, upload this `zip-with-dependencies.zip` to Amazon Device Farm.

Comment: Yes, i tried uploading the whole project, Many thanks @kelvin

Answer (score 1):

Have you packaged your tests per the AWS Device Farm instructions for [TestNG](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html) or for [JUnit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html)? Please make sure you run `mvn clean package –-DskipTests=true` to construct the package that is uploaded.

Comment: @NikofTime and @Rohan i tried the following [Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html) to create a *tests.jar and to run my script i use `mvn test -DtestNG.file=/path/to/testng.xml`